# c++ static POD initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a single instance of a simple POD

### a.hpp

```
class A {
    struct Zzz {
        A*  m_aPtr;
        int m_val;
    }

    static Zzz s_zzz;
};
```

### a.cpp

```
A::Zzz A::s_zzz;
```

I expect that both s_zzz.m_aPtr and s_zzz.m_val will be initialized to zeros before any other static initialization in any other compilation unit and it is guaranteed by the language itself. Am I right about it?

Usually I provide default constructors for the structs. Say

```
A::Zzz::Zzz() :
 m_aPtr(0),
 m_val(0)
{
}
```

Will it create initialization order problem or introduce compiler dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in C++0x, you can rely on all *zero-initialization* being performed before any other initialization code runs.

From the C++0x FCD, section `[basic.start.init]`

> Variables with static storage duration
>   (3.7.1) or thread storage duration
>   (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized
>   (8.5) before any other initialization
>   takes place.

If you're considering using this variable from other initialization code, then an explicit constructor would be a big mistake, as it would run sometime mixed in with other initialization code, and overwrite whatever changes have already been made by other initializers.

Answer (score 2):

> I expect that both s_zzz.m_aPtr and
>   s_zzz.m_val will be initialized to
>   zeros before any other static
>   initialization in any other
>   compilation unit and it is guaranteed
>   by the language itself.

It will be zero-initialized, since it's a static lifetime variable at namespace scope.

That zero-initialization happens before any dynamic initialization (an example of dynamic initializatin is when you some explicit initialization, or the class has a constructor).

The order of zero-initialization between different translation units is not defined, but there's not any way to detect it or rely on it since it happens before anything else, so it doesn't matter.

Re your point 2, it's rather unclear what you're asking about.

But for your static lifetime object, the effect is just that it's first zero-initialized, and then during dynamic initialization your constructor is used to zero it again (although the compiler might be smart enough to optimize away that redundant extra initialization).

Cheers & hth.,

**ERRATA**: Ben Voigt has provided a convincing example that *the last paragraph above is wrong*. So please disregard. The presence of the constructor means that the object can be dynamically initialized at some point before, between or after operations that change it, causing rather unpredictable results…

Comment: Wrt (2), I use to write constructors for every object, I would like to a constructor for Zzz but I am not sure whether it will screw things up.

Comment: @zzz777: the destructor you've shown won't screw things up for your static object, since it doesn't alter the state of the object. But more generally non-POD static objects at namespace scope (i.e., global variables of non-POD type, like `std::string`) can be a little dangerous. For more info on that, read up on the [**static initialization order fiasco**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14). But note that this does *not* apply to your question's case. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: It will screw things up, because it does alter the state of the object.  The state of the object is *zero-initialized* before dynamic initialization begins, but based on the question it is probably not zero throughout dynamic initialization.  Since the time at which the constructor runs relative to dynamic initialization in other compilation units is unspecified, it's UB.

Comment: @Ben: the shown constructor just zeroes already zeroed things. No difference. And it's not UB at all (if you have misunderstood some part of the standard, please do quote, but note that, for example, it's not UB to have global `std::string` (considering that may spare you a lot of work hunting for non-existing para)). Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: It's not undefined behavior to have a global `std::string` object, but it is UB to use it during dynamic initialization in another compilation unit.  On the other hand, using a global `int` object (or any POD struct) during dynamic initialization is not UB.  POD-ness matters.  "just zeroes already zeroed things"... true but meaningless.  In `int x = 0; x++; x = 0;`, do you say that the last statement doesn't do anything?  After all, `x` has already been zeroed during initialization, it makes no difference to zero it again.  Of course it makes a difference!

Comment: @Ben: I think it would help me help you if you can clarify whether you're talking about purely formal UB or not. As an example of what I mean by that, the expression `INT_MAX+1` is formal UB, but it's not UB in e.g. a Windows program (because any Windows C++ compiler defines the expression), and in particular, in that context the formal UB does not screw up things. And similarly, for the OP's code no non-perverse compiler can screw up things. Is your UB purely formal, or can you provide a concrete screw-up example for the OP's code (class with constructor, caused by non-POD-ness)?

Comment: My reading of the situation is that the constructor should not screw up the things as long as it is located in the same compilation unit with the static object itself (even if it assigns non-zero values) - but I am not sure about it and will leave it without a constructor just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Ben: sorry, I was wrong about that. you've already provided a convincing example. Thanks!

Comment: @zzz777: listen to Ben. I was wrong about this. The constructor *can* screw up things... :-( Argh. Now I need to bang my head fourteen times against nearest brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no guarantees about initialization order of statics between compilation units (see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).
2. If it has a constructor, it will no longer be a POD, unfortunately.

Comment: I trust my standard over what the FAQ says.  The FAQ is mostly likely talking about the order of execution of non-trivial constructors and initializers.  But zero-initialization DOES come first.

Comment: Re your 1, technically true, but misleading since it doesn't matter for zero-initialization of statics. Re your 2, you write "unfortunately" as if that was somehow significant; it isn't. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Becoming non-POD actually is a pretty big deal... POD-objects can be accessed as long as storage exists, while accessing non-POD objects before their constructor runs is UB.

Comment: @Alf: It can be significant; e.g. if you want your struct to be a member of a union.

Comment: @Ben, @Oli: yes, but neither applies for the OP's question. there are also more general differences, like ability to use curly braces initializer in C++98, guarantees for conversion to/from byte sequence. but, they don't apply here. cheers,

Comment: @Ben: Regarding zero-initialization, this is news to me, so I'll look into it! (having said that, I'm sure you're correct)

Comment: It seems like there is a confusion about PODs, having COPY-constructor, assignment-op or destructor will make it non-POD. But the question was about plain constructor.

Comment: @Oli: I think POD-ness IS applicable.  Consider the following code: `extern struct S { int n; } cntr; /* cntr.cpp */ S cntr; /* 1.cpp */ int i1 = ++cntr.n; /* 2.cpp */ int i2 = ++cntr.n;`  Since S is POD, `i1` and `i2` are unique and `cntr.n` is 2.  But add a constructor `S::S() : n(0) {}` and now it's possible that `cntr.n` is any of 0, 1, or 2 after initialization, and also possible that `i1` and `i2` are both 1.  Adding the constructor gives undefined behavior if the object is used during initialization in other compilation units.

Comment: @Oli: I agree with Ben now. I was wrong. And you were right with the "unfortunately". Sorry about the noise. I've not yet located brick wall to bang head against, but, searching.

Answer (score 0):

1. Static data is always initialised to zero.
2. No it shouldn't introduce any initialisation problems.

When the application is loaded into memory, the static area is initialised to zero. This is before any code starts to execute.

Comment: Well, before dynamic initializers (which are in turn before `main`) start to execute, anyway.  Some code has to run in order to load the application and allocate the static area, after all.